# How can I instantiate the constructor of the inner class for an object of the outer class?

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to implement a class, that has another class as a member.

```
class Book
{
    class Author;
}
```

In a .cpp file I am implementing the class **Author** as follows:

```
class Author
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
public:
    // the constructor for the class
    Author(string _firstName, string _lastName)
    {
        firstName = _firstName;
        lastName = _lastName;
    }
}
```

I want to do the following: in **main**, when I declare an object of class **Book**, I want it to instantiate the constructor of the class **Author**, from the code above. I was thinking of doing so by passing the parameters to the constructor of the **Book** class, and then using them to instantiate the constructor of **Author**, like this:

```
Book::Book(string a, string b)
{
    Book::Author(a, b);
}
```

But if I do so, if I have another inner class, as a member of the class **Book**, that has, let's say - 4 members, I would have too many parameters for the constructor of **Book**.

So my question is: is there another way to instantiate the constructor of a class that is a member when I create an object of the main class?

And also, how do I print the members of that main class, if these members are classes? I tried to overload the << operator for the inner classes, but I get the error: "invalid use of nonstatic data member."

Comment: @juanchopanza Any data members, you mean. It does have a member class, but not a data member of that (member) class type.

Comment: 'Instantiate the constructor' is meaningless. There is no inner class here. Unclear what you're asking, or talking about,

Comment: @Angew I meant any members. Does a class declaration count as a member?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Objects of types Book and Author are completely unrelsted. If you want each book to have an author, you need to add sn Author data member to class Book. (Then some books have no authors, or many authors).

Comment: @juanchopanza I'll double check the standard, but I'd assume so. After all, `Author` has access to the non-public names in `Book`, just like any other member would.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, it does. And it *is* a member. C++14 N4140 9.2/1: "Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and
enumerators." And 11/1&2 states that members have access to `private` and `protected` names. BTW, this "member classes have access to private" is a change from C++03 to C++11.

Comment: @reevesCFC Your question shows some rather basic misconceptions about how C++ works. You might want to read through a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) or tutorial. That should give you a better overall grasp than asking piecewise questions on SO.

Comment: Also note that you seem to have an undefined class Book::Author and an unrelated class ::Author defined in the .cpp file.

Comment: @juanchopanza Which declares a nested type. It's true that the type is *not* defined by the `Author` definition inside the OP's cpp file, though.

Comment: @juanchopanza 9.7/3: "If class `X` is defined in a namespace scope, a nested class `Y` may be declared in class `X` and later defined in the
definition of class `X` or be later defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of class `X`."

Comment: @juanchopanza "or be later defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of class `X`." Sure, you'd have to define it as `Book::Author` at that namespace scope, but you don't have to define it lexically inside the containing class.

Comment: @Angew You're right, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @n.m. I mean in your example you didn't define `A::B`, you defined a different type `::B` that is not the nested type. That caused some confusion. Here's [an example that shows the definition of the nested type outside of the nesting type's definition](http://ideone.com/Yt5nly). That's the kind of example I was asking for. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not your real code because there are extremely basic compilation errors (missing semicolons).

Answer (score 3):

I think you've made a mistake about C++ inner class. There is no *inner class* only **nested class** which is not the same.

A **Nested class** is a class whose definition/declaration is made inside the definition/declaration of another one. But, this relation is a relation on **types** not on instances of the class.

If you want to have an author for a book you have to build an aggregate or similar, like this:

```
class Book {
  class Author {
    string name;
    // How to initialize an author (give him a name)
    Author(string n) : name(n) { }
  };
  string title;
  Author theAuthorOfTheBook;
  // How to initialize a book (giving him a title and setting up an author with a given name)

  public :
  Book(string t,string n) : title(t), theAuthorOfTheBook(n) {}
};
```

The *nested* definition is interesting because you may have some other concept of *authoring* for different purpose and not related to book authoring. This nested definition will let you easily talk about book authoring (`Book::Author`).

I added a field `theAuthorOfTheBook` to define an **attribute** for the Book concept. This will probably need to be initialized at Book's construction (see ctors definition).

Comment: Thank you. That was quite helpful, got me the basic idea, and I even did the title as a class. If you don't mind me asking, how can I print out the members of the class "Book", if they are all classes? I'm aware of the overloading of the << operator, but it didn't work for me just because the members of the class "Book" are not simple data types, but classes.

Comment: This is another question, but simply each class has to provide its own `<<` overloading.